# How to force remove a file on my disk with permissions I am unable to reset?

Tags: disk-utility, permission

I downloaded anaconda and I accidentally started to download it onto my top-level directory, the disk itself, and I cannot remove it. I can't change the name, and when I change the permissions from read only to read and write for admin, everyone, and myself, it says I do not have permission to delete the folder. I'm also confused about why I'm not admin when I should be. Regardless, I've tried to force delete it and it's not working.

When I try to download it again, it says I can't download anaconda because the folder already exists, so I'm downloading python in the opt folder on my disk-utility and it's freezing. IDK what's wrong with this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of **macOS**? Where exactly did you download the file to, What's it path? In **Terminal** have you tried to _change directory_ to where `folder_name` is and then use `sudo rm -rf folder_name`? **Warning:** `sudo rm -rf ...` can be extremely dangerous if not used properly. If you are not sure of it's usage then seek help. You have been warned!

Comment: The absolute top library with the following folders: Applications, Library, Systems, Users. When running sudo rm -rf it said I don't have permission to delete folder.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean that you accidentally started to "install" (rather than download) it into the top-level directory. Can you provide a full (ls -l) directory listing of the directory you did the install in from the Terminal app or a screenshot of the directory location showing the top-level folder of the install.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the install package from the site https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual and ran through a default install. It looks like the application is installed in /opt. You will need to use

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/anaconda3
```

to delete. Please review terminal session below:

---

```
(base) users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ cd /opt

(base) users-MacBook-Pro:opt user$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  26 user  wheel  884  4 May 14:22 anaconda3

(base) users-MacBook-Pro:opt user$ rm -rf anaconda3
rm: anaconda3: Permission denied

(base) users-MacBook-Pro:opt user$ sudo rm -rf anaconda3
Password:

(base) users-MacBook-Pro:opt user$ ls -l
total 0
```